# ASP.NET MVC 3 Url.Action matching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following two routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "" // ~/  
                ,new { controller="Products", action="List", page=1 });

routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/Page{page}" // ~/CategoryName/Page21  
                , new { controller = "Products", action = "List", page = 1 }
                , new { page = @"\d+" } //page must be numerical
                );
```

I am generating a URL using this code in the view being used by ProductsController: `Url.Action("List", new {page=p, category=Model.CurrentCategory})`

With the current configuration, I get this URL: **/Riding/Page2**

However, if I omit the default **page** parameter from the first route, I get this URL instead: **/?category=Riding&page=2**

It seems to me that `Url.Action()` can match both routes and is making a decision to use the second route if I have the default **page** parameter specified in the first route but is choosing to use the first route if that parameter is omitted.

Given that I am supplying a value for **page** parameter, why would eliminating it from the route's defaults make a difference in the URL I get back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the NuGet package [Glimpse](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse). It has excellent route debugging, it should be able to help you.

Here's a blog post by Scott Hanselan on how to use it: [NuGet Package of the Week #5](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, @JamesAllen. I tried Glimpse. It shows me the route that was matched to serve my page. I couldn't find any info that would tell me why Url.Action() on my view selected the routes I mentioned in my post.